# How to get screen size from within a Portable Class Library?

Tags: c#, .net, portable-class-library

So in a normal .net assembly I can access `SystemInformation.VirtualScreen`. How would this be done from within a PCL?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I'd do:

1. Introduce an abstraction for `IVirtualScreen` in your PCL project
2. In your Desktop class library (which references the PCL project), provide an adapter class to map the `SystemInformation.VirtualScreen` to your IVirtualScreen interface.
3. When bootstrapping your desktop application, register the platform-specific version with your IoC container.

   ```
   // in your PCL project
   public interface IVirtualScreen {
        Rectangle Current { get; 
   }


   // in your desktop project
   public interface DesktopScreen : IVirtualScreen {
      public Rectangle Current { 
        get {
           return System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.VirtualScreen;
      }
   }
   ```

But this begs the question: is this something you require in your PCL project?

With the radical differences between UI technologies (WinForms/WPF/SL/WP7/WP8/WinRT) you could end up doing lots of platform-specific things, and while you *could* plug in a different implementation of IVirtualScreen for a mobile application, is there value in doing this?

Comment: Creating an abstraction like this is generally the right idea.  However, in this case I'm wondering why you would need to get the current screen size in a portable library.  Nothing related to the UI is really portable, so I wouldn't expect code that needed to know the screen size to generally go in a portable library.  Also, the Rectangle type is also not portable so you'd need to create your own type for that.

Comment: "Also, the Rectangle type is also not portable" Ah yes, my bad. But you get the picture anyway...

Comment: If possible I would prefer to pass the width and height as parameters if you really need them in a PCL. Simpler is better.